# Find computer accounts not in group A or group B

Tags: powershell

I have two security groups that are used for group policies security filtering. These are used to stagger windows update every month. The issue that has risen, is that I cannot keep up with new servers coming online. So I would like to automate a powershell script that will email me a list of servers that are not found in group A or group B. I have some of the code but I just can't seem to get my head wrapped around it.

```
    #Grab the computer names from the first security group
    $group1 = Get-ADGroup -Identity 'Every Day WSUS 3am Install'
    $members1 = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group1 | select -Expand Name

    #Grab the computer names from the second security group
    $group2 = Get-ADGroup -Identity 'Every Day WSUS 6am Install'
    $members2 = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group2 | select -Expand Name

    #grab all computer obejects that are servers from AD and list the names not found in either security group
    (Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter "(&(objectcategory=computer)(OperatingSystem=*server*))").Name | ? { $members1 -notcontains $_.Name -and $members2 -notcontains $_.Name }
```

Answer (score 5):

You wrapped your `Get-ADComputer` command in `().Name` so that would return a bunch of strings that are a the name attribute. When you compare the Name string against the computer object, it won't compare nicely. Try this method:

```
#Grab the computer names from the first security group
$group1 = Get-ADGroup -Identity 'Every Day WSUS 3am Install'
$group2 = Get-ADGroup -Identity 'Every Day WSUS 6am Install'

#grab all computer obejects that are servers from AD and list the names not found in either security group
Get-ADComputer `
    -LDAPFilter "(&(objectcategory=computer)(OperatingSystem=*server*))" `
    -Properties MemberOf | 
Where-Object {
    ( $_.MemberOf -notcontains $Group1.DistinguishedName ) -and
    ( $_.MemberOf -notcontains $Group2.DistinguishedName )
} |
Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

Comment: It says less than 15 reputation points shows it recorded but won't display. I will come back when I have 15 and try again. Thanks again for your quick response.

Comment: dont worry shawn and the tram i am giving it a thumps up

Comment: I added on a $varible before the Get-ADComputer so I can place it in the body of an email alert. I am having difficulty trying to get it to single name on each line. So when an email comes through, it has all the names seperated by a space. Just curious, thanks Owl for your help

Comment: $EmailBodyContent = $Variable -join "`n"